# nginx, why auth_request cannot be used in if section

Tags: java, nginx

I am trying to make a custom authentication request only for POST method in Nginx. And I found auth_request module, so I wrote something like this:

```
location /api/books {
  if ($request_method = GET) {
     proxy_pass http://bookservice;
  }
  auth_request /api/auth;
  proxy_pass http://bookservice;
}
location /api/auth {
  proxy_pass http://authservice;
}
```

bookservice and authservice are two upstreams. I first tried this, it doesn't work: everytime there is a GET /api/books, it fires the subrequest to auth service. The expected behavior is: when it is GET /api/books, it does NOT fire subrequest to auth service, otherwise, it fires the subrequest to auth service.

So I wrote something like:

```
location /api/books {
  if ($request_method = GET) {
     proxy_pass http://bookservice;
  }
  if ($request_method = POST) {
    auth_request /api/auth;
    proxy_pass http://bookservice;
  }
}
location /api/auth {
  proxy_pass http://authservice;
}
```

But when reloading the config, it says: "auth_request" directive is not allowed here in.

I understand that auth_request cannot be in if, it can only be in location, server, http. But how to achieve my objective, and why it cannot be applied inside if?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'd like some resources to not be protected for GET requests as well.

Answer (score 7):

I did something like this today. Came to this solution:

```
location /api/books {
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        rewrite .* /_api/books last;
    }
    proxy_pass http://bookservice;
}

location /_api/books {
    rewrite .* /api/books break;
    auth_request /api/auth;
    proxy_pass http://bookservice;
    internal;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Would be much nicer with an if, but I don't know why it isn't allowed. However "if" is discouraged by nginx (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: You might want to add the ’internal;’ directive to your _api location so it can only be reached by an nginx rewrite.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I was struggling to figure out a way for this..